# Publish one Single SP/Function from SSDT

Tags: database, sql-server-data-tools

Can I quickly publish one/more specific stored procedure or other small changes quickly instead of publishing the full SSDT project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your only option to do that is going to be to copy out that code and push the changes over using SSMS or similar. SSDT projects/publish is designed to make the target look like the source - and that's all changes.

You might be able to do some source control to make those small changes as one-offs in a branch and publish from that branch, but again - it will still do a complete comparison to make the target look like the source.

Comment: Thanks @PeterSmith, that's what I am doing now.

Comment: This extension seems to be doing what you want  https://github.com/GoEddie/SSDTExtension  but it's not up-to-date. I searched for something similar but couldn't find anything. I wonder why since this seems to me to be a fairly common use case!? In a real-life workflow wouldn't that be used often? 

-OR-

Developers actually code/debug directly in the database (in SSMS or VS) and eventually move back their code from the database to the project in SSDT?
What am I missing?

Comment: My most common use case was to make changes to my local copy of the database, pull those into my project using a schema compare, and commit those to a branch. When all of those were good, I'd merge mainline into my branch, resolve conflicts, and submit a pull request. All of the changes were then deployed at the same time. We didn't do a lot of one-off/cherry-picked changes to a database from the project.